# How to alert user about unsaved changes in a React npm module library?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, node-modules

In one of my components **in a React npm module library** (a library shared among projects), I need to alert the user about unsaved changes, which means, I have to notify the user before the component unmounts.

I have done a bunch of research, and the only possible way of doing that is through using a router (using like < Prompt /> or setRouteLeaveHook, as SPA doesn't unload the page to navigate between pages.

Since npm modules don't really own the < Router /> components (the React projects using those modules own it), doing anything related to Router seem to yield to the error as shown below:

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use "anything-router-related" outside a <Router>
```

Is there any way to alert the user about unsaved changes without using react-router **in a React npm module library**?  Or else how to properly use react router in a react npm module library?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's possible to nest Router within BrowserRouter from react-router-dom, all you need to do is to pass the history prop from the BrowserRouter to the Router from react-router-dom.  I have searched around and nobody seemed to mention that one can nest a router within a router.

For the app implementing the library:

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <TopNav />
        <div style={{ margin: 30 }}>
          <Library history={this.props.history} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
)
}
```

For the Library, grab the history props passed.  Right now, the Alert User Unsaved Changes Prompt can be dealt with within the react-npm-module-library:

```
render() {
if (this.props.data) {
  return (
    <Router history={this.props.history}>
       <Prompt when message='Are you sure you want to leave?' />
    </Router>
  )
}
}
```